# How do you hide from hasattr?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let's say a function looks at an object and checks if it has a function `a_method`:

```
def func(obj):
    if hasattr(obj, 'a_method'):
        ...
    else:
        ...
```

I have an object whose class defines `a_method`, but I want to *hide* it from `hasattr`. I don't want to change the implementation of `func` to achieve this hiding, so what hack can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: You could redefine `hasattr`.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's a really nasty thing to do. Also, `hasattr` checks whether `obj.a_method` exists by just trying to access it, so you'd have to make the attribute *only exist when `hasattr` isn't looking*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the method is defined on the class you appear to be able to remove it from the `__dict__` for the class.  This prevents lookups (hasattr will return false).  You can still use the function if you keep a reference to it when you remove it (like the example) - just remember that you have to pass in an instance of the class for self, it's not being called with the implied *self*.

```
>>> class A:
...   def meth(self):
...     print "In method."
...
>>>
>>> a = A()
>>> a.meth
<bound method A.meth of <__main__.A instance at 0x0218AB48>>
>>> fn = A.__dict__.pop('meth')
>>> hasattr(a, 'meth')
False
>>> a.meth
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: A instance has no attribute 'meth'
>>> fn()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: meth() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
>>> fn(a)
In method.
```

Comment: This is pretty much equivalent to not putting the method in the class at all and just defining a module-level function for it.

Comment: @user2357112 - but avoids the need to modify the definition of the class and is achieved at runtime.

Comment: But if you're not in a position to change the class definition, you're probably not in a position to change all the code that depends on that method being there.

Answer (score 1):

You could redefine the hasattr function. Below is an example.

```
saved_hasattr = hasattr    

def hasattr(obj, method):
  if method == 'MY_METHOD':
    return False
  else:
    return saved_hasattr(obj, method)
```

Note that you probably want to implement more detailed checks than just checking the method name. For example checking the object type might be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Test(object):

    def __hideme(self):
        print 'hidden'


t = Test()

print hasattr(t,"__hideme") #prints False....
```

I believe this works b/c of the double underscore magic of hiding members (owning to name mangling) of a class to outside world...Unless someone has a strong argument against this, I'd think this is way better than popping stuff off from `__dict__`? Thoughts?